# Apache Airflow Task Instance state is blank

Tags: airflow, databricks, airflow-scheduler

I have the dag config like below

```
    args = {
        'owner': 'XXX',
        'depends_on_past': False,
        'start_date': datetime(2018, 2, 26),
        'email': ['sample@sample.com'],
        'email_on_failure': False,
        'retries': 1,
        'retry_delay': timedelta(minutes=5)
    }

   dag = DAG(dag_id='Daily_Report',
      default_args=args,
      schedule_interval='0 11 * * *',
      dagrun_timeout=timedelta(seconds=30))
```

I have a bash operator and a data bricks operator

```
   run_this = BashOperator(task_id='run_report',
               bash_command=templated_command,
               dag=dag)

  notebook_run = DatabricksSubmitRunOperator(
         task_id='notebook_run',
         notebook_task=notebook_task,
         existing_cluster_id='xxxx',
         dag=dag)
```

I'm running this like run_this.set_downstream(notebook_run)

The bash operator runs fine but the data bricks operator doesn't run it just leaves a blank state like below

Blank Status Airflow

[image]

Any thing I'm missing ? Im using Airflow version from Databricks here https://github.com/databricks/incubator-airflow

Comment: Have you checked if all components are up and running? See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49021055/airflow-1-9-0-is-queuing-but-not-launching-tasks/

Comment: Yes. All the components are up and running. If I trigger the dag manually it completes both the jobs.

Answer (score 2):

Try highlighting the text in the white label. It will probably say "None". White on white is terrible UX so I'm not sure why Airflow does it that way.

[image]