# airflow task with scheduled state hanging

Tags: python, airflow, airflow-scheduler

I am using airflow 1.8.1 and there was wired behavior and I tried to figure out. What it happened was I cleared a running task and airflow marked it as "shutdown", then I tried to rerun so cleared again. Now that task will be put as "scheduled" state but scheduler won't pick it up, anyone has similar issue? what is the appropriate way to do this?

[image]

Comment: Have you checked all those things: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49021055/airflow-1-9-0-is-queuing-but-not-launching-tasks/49047832#49047832

Comment: Can you reproduce this in the current release of Airflow (1.9.0)?