# Why is a task stuck and not executed in airflow?

Tags: airflow, airflow-scheduler

I'm trying out airflow with the `BigQueryOperator`. I thought I would use google composer later on, but I want it running locally first. I have airflow up and running an `BashOperator` works fine, I can also run `airflow test <dag> <task>` where `task` is the big query task I want to run, but when I trigger the DAG from the UI the bigquery task is never queued. Instead they have the `REMOVED` state and nothing happens.

My DAG definition looks like this:

```
from airflow import DAG
from airflow.operators.bash_operator import BashOperator
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
from airflow.contrib.operators.bigquery_operator import BigQueryOperator

yesterday = datetime.combine(
    datetime.today() - timedelta(1),
datetime.min.time())

default_args = {
    'owner': 'airflow',
    'depends_on_past': False,
    'email': ['airflow@example.com'],
    'start_date': yesterday,
    'email_on_failure': False,
    'email_on_retry': False,
    'retries': 1,
    'retry_delay': timedelta(minutes=5),
}

with DAG(
        'tutorial', default_args=default_args) as dag:

operators
    t1 = BashOperator(
        task_id='print_date',
        bash_command='date')

    template_sql = '''
            SELECT 'TOMAS' name, '{{ params.my_value }}' value, "{{ params.my_value2 }}" tables
        '''

    sampleBigQuery1 = BigQueryOperator(
        task_id='bq_simple_sql1',
        bql=template_sql,
        use_legacy_sql=False,
        destination_dataset_table='temp_tomas.airflow_1',
        allow_large_results=True,
        params={'my_value': (datetime.now()).strftime("%D %T"),
                'my_value2': "yolo"},  # getTables()},
        create_disposition='CREATE_IF_NEEDED',
        write_disposition='WRITE_TRUNCATE'
    )

    t1 >> sampleBigQuery1
```

So how do I debug a case when it works to run `airflow test ...` but not when it triggered by scheduler or UI? Is it something that seems to be wrong with what I have here?

Locally I'm using a standard install of airflow with sqllite, but that shouldn't have any impact I think. I am running everything in one python env, so it should be pretty contained.

Answer (score 8):

If this is your first Airflow setup, you might want to check those things first: [Airflow 1.9.0 is queuing but not launching tasks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49021055/airflow-1-9-0-is-queuing-but-not-launching-tasks/49047832#49047832)

Additionally, here I'd recommend especially the last step:

- If nothing else works, you can use the web ui to click on the dag, then on Graph View. Now select the first task and click on Task Instance. In the paragraph Task Instance Details you will see why a DAG is waiting or not running.

This might give you more of an idea why the task is not being scheduled.

Comment: I have checked the instance details, and the state is: `Task is in the 'removed' state which is not a valid state for execution. The task must be cleared in order to be run.` But I have no idea why it is in `removed` state. As I said above, if I try to run `airflow test` on the specific task it works. Also, in general everything else works. I can run DAGs that consists of multiple `BashOperator` without any problem.

Comment: @TomasJansson Did you try `airflow clear` as well for this task?

Comment: This is curious since REMOVED state is usually for exactly that, removed tasks which were there before but which have been removed from the DAG.

Comment: I renamed the file and also the name of the DAG and copied the file to the dags folder again and it seems to be working.

Comment: Thanks, @TomasJansson You should post your comment as an answer to the question. Renaming the dag fixed it for me, at least for now.