# Airflow UI pause toggle not showing for tutorial

Tags: airflow

I am following the [tutorial in the Airflow docs](https://airflow.apache.org/tutorial.html). When I visit the UI I don't see the toggle to turn on and off (or pause?) the DAGs

[image]

I tried to click the trigger DAG button on the right but I guess this just manually runs it once ignoring the scheduler. (A side question, it just says it's running now, it isn't finishing... is it waiting for something?)

So, did I have to do something in order to schedule the DAG first and is that why I'm not seeing a pause button, because it isn't scheduled? that would surprise me because surely I should be able to schedule it from the UI?

Lastly, what are all those other example DAGs and how can I hide them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems to me that some part of your Airflow setup is broken.

Either the scheduler is not working or the files are not deployed.

My suggestion is to check this question as well: [Airflow 1.9.0 is queuing but not launching tasks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49021055/airflow-1-9-0-is-queuing-but-not-launching-tasks/49047832#49047832)

Comment: I did not run `airflow scheduler` :/