# Why does Airflow changing start_date without renaming dag?

Tags: airflow, airflow-scheduler

I am a data engineer and work with airflow regularly.

When redeploying dags with a new start date the best practice is as shown in the [here](https://gtoonstra.github.io/etl-with-airflow/gotchas.html):

> **Don’t change start_date + interval**: When a DAG has been run, the scheduler database contains instances of the run of that DAG. If you change the start_date or the interval and redeploy it, the scheduler may get confused because the intervals are different or the start_date is way back. The best way to deal with this is to change the version of the DAG as soon as you change the start_date or interval, i.e. my_dag_v1 and my_dag_v1. This way, historical information is also kept about the old version.

However after deleting all previous DAG and task runs I tried to redeploy a dag with a new start date. It worked as expected (with the new start date) for a day, then started to work with the old again

What are the reasons for this? In depth if you can.

Comment: Airflow's `scheduler` is [complex and mysterious](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/AIRFLOW/Scheduler+Basics) engineering. It has its fair share of nuances, and [major changes](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/AIRFLOW/AIP-18+Persist+all+information+from+DAG+file+in+DB) have been proposed. Till then [People recommend](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49088553/3679900) to restart it periodically (which is true for pretty much every long-running process). At the least changing `start_date` or `schedule_interval` calls for an immediate restart (or you'll be in for some surprises)

Answer (score 3):

Airflow maintains all of the information regarding the past runs in a table `dag_run`.

When you clear the previous dag runs, these entries are dropped from the database. Hence, airflow treats this dag as a new dag and starts at the specified time.

Airflow checks the last dag execution time (`start_date` of last run) and adds the `timedelta` object which you have specified in `schedule_interval`.

If you are having difficulties even after clearing dag runs, few things you can do:

1. Rename the dag as suggested.
2. Clear all the dag runs, keep the dag paused. Create a dag run and then turn the dag on. It will run on the scheduled time afterwards.
3. **The best approach would be to use crontab expression inside `schedule_interval`**.

Comment: I did 3.

`SCHEDULE_INTERVAL = '0 4 * * *'`

I am purposefully trying to avoid 1.
Also 2 makes no sense since I made it work the first day and then it misbehaved.