# Why my Dag is not running if the updated schedule interval is less than the previous schedule interval of the dag

Tags: airflow, airflow-scheduler

I am running a workflow with the `schedule_interval` of 15mins. Now after completing the execution of the workflow, I have modified the configuration of the workflow and updated the `schedule_interval` to 10 mins.

In this case it is creating some instances based on the difference between the last execution date and current start date and in those instances the task are not getting started, just the dag is shown in running state constantly.

How can I restrict these extra instances or can make them failed by default?

Let the `Start date` of the DAG is 29/7/2019T12:00PM
`Schedule Interval` is 15min.
Now let after running two instances at 12:32PM I have update the workflow `schedule_interval` to 10 mins and the `start_date` to current date i.e. 29/7/2019T12:32PM.

In this case as the `last execution date` of the dag was 29/7/2019T12:30PM.
No according to the `last execution date` and the updated `schedule_interval` the next instance should run at 12:40PM, but `next execution date` according to the `previous schedule_interval` is 12:45.

So it won't run this instance. and will give dependency error saying:

```
your execution date is less than the start date.
```

Answer (score 5):

- The [fool-proof way](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38028555/3679900) of dodging such misbehaviours by `scheduler` is to not *confuse* it, i.e. **do NOT change the `schedule_interval` of a DAG**. In other words, if you have to to modify schedule interval of a DAG, just **rename it**; which will make airflow *forget* the old DAG and treat the renamed DAG as a brand new one
- But my [anecdotal tip](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57096386/why-does-airflow-changing-start-date-without-renaming-dag#comment100720301_57096386) is that if you ever happen to (say accidently) modify the schedule interval of a DAG, **restarting the Airflow scheduler** / webserver processes also solves the problem.

Comment: Adding to this answer, the airflow scheduler has a flag `--num_runs` where you can specify how many scheduler loops to run before the scheduler stops itself. This can be a convenient way to frequently restart the airflow scheduler to help mitigate scheduler oddities like in the second bullet point.