# can we parameterize the airflow schedule_interval dynamically reading from the variables instead of passing as the cron expression

Tags: airflow-scheduler, airflow

**can we parameterize the airflow schedule_interval dynamically reading from the airflow variables instead of passing directly as the cron expression**

I have passed the following way as per airflow documentation
args = {
'owner': 'pavan',
'depends_on_past': False,
'start_date': datetime(2020, 1, 15),
'email_on_failure': True,
'email_on_retry': False,
'retries': 0,
'on_failure_callback': notify_email
}

with DAG(dag_id=DAG_NAME, default_args=args, schedule_interval='* 1 * * *', catchup=False) as dag:

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes

Technically you can do it, but it brings 2 problems

- *minor problem*: reading a Variable means a SQL-query being fired to Airflow's `SQLAlchemy` backend meta-db. And doing it in your DAG-definition script means this will happen as the DAG is continuously parsed by Airflow in background. Read [point 2 here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63255612/3679900)
- *major problem*: A Variable can be edited via UI. But altering an `Airflow` DAG's `schedule_interval` can have wierd behaviours and may require you to either [rename the DAG](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37294560/3679900) or (anecdotal finding) [restart the `scheduler`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57096386/why-does-airflow-changing-start-date-without-renaming-dag#comment100720301_57096386) to fix that