# Airflow v2.2.5 on MWAA v2.0.2 is queuing but not running DAG tasks

Tags: docker, airflow, mwaa

I'm running Airflow v2.2.5 on MWAA v2.0.2 locally on Docker v20.10.12. I checked the basic debugging checklist for such cases (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49047832/17645092)) but I don't see any issue with scheduler or webserver not running, improper start date or schedule, etc.

Here's what I see when looking at (Task) Instance details:

- *Dagrun Running*: Task instance's dagrun was not in the 'running' state but in the state 'queued'.
- *Task Instance State*: Task is in the 'None' state.

I'm not sure what else to look up to fix this issue. Obviously, there are no logs since the task hasn't started.

Comment: which executor are you using?

Comment: @HusseinAwala SequentialExecutor